# Dictionary from csv file to group different names in a column

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing an assignment where I have a csvfile and I have to generate matplot lib graphs. I have a column full of genres of different movies, with the genres seperated by | (vertical bar). I have to create a dictionary of these genres, once, without repeating, to assign them to the appropriate movies. How will I go about doing that?
this is what I have so far:

```
import csv


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


dp = open("C:\Users\jayan\OneDrive\Desktop\IMDB_movie_metadata_for_assignment_6.csv",'r', encoding='utf8').read()

with open("C:\Users\jayan\OneDrive\Desktop\IMDB_movie_metadata_for_assignment_6.csv", errors = 'ignore') as csvfile:

for line in csvfile:
    fields = line.split(",")
    newField = (fields[4]).split("|")

    newerField = fields[16].strip()
    movies = (fields[0])

    genre_dictionary = {tuple(newField):(movies)}
    print(genre_dictionary)
```

Comment: What is your issue ? Could you put here an image of part of your csv so that I can reproduce it ?

Comment: @python123 I have added the image, I want to collect all the genres such as adventures, sci fi, romance and so on in the column and put it in a dictionary so that it can be the key and the values would be the movies belonging to each of the genres. How will I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose your csv has two columns: `genres` and `movies`. Tell me if it's not the case. You can do something like:

```
def find_col_ind(columns):
    ind = -1
    ind_col_genres = -1
    ind_col_movie = -1
    
    for col in columns:
        ind += 1
                    
        if col == 'movie_title':
            ind_col_movie = ind
        elif col == 'genres':
            ind_col_genres = ind 

    return ind_col_genres, ind_col_movie



def create_dict(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        data = dict()
        is_first = True

        for line in csvfile:
            columns = line.split(',')

            if is_first:
                ind_col_genres, ind_col_movie = find_col_ind(columns)
                is_first = False
                continue

            genres = columns[ind_col_genres].split('|')
            movie = columns[ind_col_movie]

            for genre in genres:
                if genre in data:
                    data[genre].append(movie.strip('\nÂ\xa0 '))
                else:
                    data[genre] = [movie.strip('\nÂ\xa0 ')]

        return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = create_dict('test.csv')
    print(data)
```

Comment: Will try this, although I can't print the data for the code you have given. Also, how would I go about movie being represented by a list or a tuple of all the data values
for that movie, so that as soon as you read in and process the information
for a movie, you can add it to all the appropriate lists?

Comment: If you have a csv like:


genres,movies
Action|Adventure,Avatar
Drama|Action|Romance,Titanic


Supposing you have already loaded it into a python object, the function I gave you will return a dict like:


{'Action': ['Avatar', 'Titanic'], 'Adventure': ['Avatar'], 'Drama': ['Titanic'], 'Romance': ['Titanic']}

Are you searching for something like this ?

Comment: Yeah, the file has columns like genres, movies, directors, budget, etc and I am looking for exactly what you said. I am not sure why it is not returning the output by printing. I also have to assign the rest of the categories I have to the appropriate movies represented by a list or a tuple of all the data values
for that movie. And as soon as you read in and process the information
for a movie,  it can be added to all the appropriate lists.

Comment: I edited it with an example of use. Substitute the 'test.csv' string by the name of your file

Comment: Doesn't it return the same thing that I have and not what you mentioned, for example:  {'Action': ['Avatar', 'Titanic'], 'Adventure': ['Avatar'], 'Drama': ['Titanic'], 'Romance': ['Titanic']}?

Comment: It is giving the right dict with a csv I created for tests. What is it giving for your dict ?

Comment: It is giving me the movie and the genre one by one. The csv file I have has almost 5000 movies and genres for those, so it is listing out one by one

Comment: Can you give me a link to your csv ?

Comment: yep! here it is - https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoIBoh8LkgoFyllv8Qp0pBQMqFtB?e=ZaWxWJ

Comment: I edited the script. Now it's working with your csv. Substitute 'test.csv' by your csv. Let me know if it's what you are searching for.

Comment: It works now, thank you very much! Would you happen to know how I would put the other components into a list/tuple to match the movies?

Comment: @Shri Please, accept the answer and create a new question. StackOverflow is supposed to be used with one question per topic.